# Find all the possible paths in csv file

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, csv, path

I have a csv file that has the following format:

```
header1,header2,header3,header4
1,4,2,5
1,4,0,5
0,4,2,5
```

The relevant information for my question is only in column 1 and column 3. I'm trying to find all the possible paths in this csv file where two values are connected (in a directed path) if they are in the same row. For example, in the above data:

```
1 is connected to 2
1 is connected to 0
0 is connected to 2
```

Then all the possible paths are:

```
[1,2]
[1,0,2]
[0,2]
```

With the help of online resources (specifically [this](https://www.quora.com/How-should-I-find-all-distinct-simple-paths-between-2-given-nodes-in-an-undirected-graph)) I've been able to find all the paths for a specified starting node and end node. The following is my code:

```
import csv  
def main():
   inputFile = "file_directory"
   a =[]
   with open(inputFile) as csvfile:
      reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      next(reader)
      for line in reader:
         a.append([line[0], line[2]])
   # This will print all the paths starting with 1 and ending with 2
   print(str(getAllSimplePaths('1', '2', a)))


def getAllSimplePaths(originNode, targetNode, a):
      return helpGetAllSimplePaths(targetNode,
                         [originNode],
                         set(originNode),
                         a,
                         list())


def helpGetAllSimplePaths(targetNode, currentPath, usedNodes, a, answerPaths):
  lastNode = currentPath[-1]
  if lastNode == targetNode:
    answerPaths.append(list(currentPath))
  else:
    for elem in a:
      if elem[0] == lastNode:
        if elem[1] not in usedNodes:
          currentPath.append(elem[1])
          usedNodes.add(elem[1])
          helpGetAllSimplePaths(targetNode,currentPath,usedNodes,a,answerPaths)
          usedNodes.remove(elem[1])
          currentPath.pop()
  return answerPaths               


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

When I run this, I correctly get the following result:

```
[['1', '2'], ['1', '0', '2']]
```

However, what I really want to do is be able to loop through all the elements in the second column of my csv file and find all the possible paths for each element. I've been working on this for days and I can't figure out a way to do this. My csv file has about 2000 rows. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

UPDATE: Extra Information

Each row in the csv file is already a path between two elements. So the number of paths I have will be equal to the number of rows I have in my csv file. Now, starting with the first row in the example of my question, 1 is connected to 2 and therefore ['1','2'] is a path. For each row I want to find what the element (elem1) in the first column is connected to, by looking at the same row third column (elem2) and then search all the rows in the csv file for elem2 in the first column. If it exists in the first column for some row then elem2 must be connected to a corresponding element in the same row third column (elem3). In this case our path is [elem1,elem2,elem3]. Similarly for elem3 I will have to look through all the rows to see if it exists in the first column. If it doesn't exist then I'm done for the first path. Next I move on to the second path.

The desired output for the example above would look like this:

```
[['1','2'], ['1', '0', '2'], ['0', '2'], ['1','0']]
```

I'm using Python 3.5.1.

Comment: Is there a possibility for cycles, e.g. is there a case where `1` is connected to `0` and `0` is connected to `1`? If yes what's the desired output in that case?

Comment: Yes, there is a possibility of cycles. However, the code above is designed to detect that and not allow for a cycle to happen. For example if 1 is connected to 2 and 2 is connected to 1 the program will only output [['1', '2']] given that 1 is the start node and 2 is the end node.

Comment: First I suggest you fix the indentation of the code in your question. Also, what does "all the possible paths for each element" mean—paths from what to what?

Comment: This may be a premature (without thinking through your code) and naive question, but it occurs to me that perhaps storing positional information may be of value. I will review your code, but for now, using your example, would there be value in saying col1:1 is connected to col3:2, col1:1 is connected to col3:0, col1:0 is connected to col3:2, therefore, col1:1 connects to col3:2, col1:1 connects to col3:0 and col3:2, col1:0 connects to col3:2? Whether this adds value or not, am I interpreting the possible paths correctly in your examples?

Comment: @martineau I have fixed the indentation. Each row in the csv file is already a path between two elements. So the number of paths I have will be equal to the number of rows I have in my csv file. Now, starting with the first row in the example of my question, 1 is connected to 2 and therefore ['1','2'] is a path.

Comment: @martineau for each row I want to find what the element (elem1) in the first column is connected to, by looking at the same row third column (elem2) and then search all the rows in the csv file for elem2 in the first column. If it exists in the first column for some row then elem2 must be connected to a corresponding element in the same row third column (elem3). In this case our path is [elem1,elem2,elem3]. Similarly for elem3 I will have to look through all the rows to see if it exists in the first column. If it doesn't exist then I'm done for the first path. Next I move on to the second path

Comment: OK, that looks like enough info. It would actually be best if you would [edit] your question and add it there rather than having it just down here. Also, can you provide the expected output if it did what you want (based on the sample input)?

Comment: @martineau I added the extra information and Python version. An expected output is already added in the question. Thanks.

Comment: The output shown in your question is just the paths starting with 1 and ending with 2, not every possible path in the csv. The latter is what I meant.

Comment: @martineau right, I have updated it. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the desired output also have to include `['1', '0']` by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

Here's a version I've optimized a bit more. Before you use it on a really large csv file, I suggest you remove some/most of the printing it does—which won't affect the final results.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint, pformat

def main():
    inputFile = "paths.csv"
    with open(inputFile, newline='') as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
       next(reader)
       a = [[row[0], row[2]] for row in reader]
    print('a:\n', pformat(a))

    # construct an adjacency *dictionary*
    nodeToNodes = {}
    for src, dst in a:
        nodeToNodes.setdefault(src, []).append(dst)
    print('\nnodeToNodes:\n', pformat(nodeToNodes))

    print('\ngathering results:')
    all_paths = []
    for src, dst in a:
        print('  {} <-> {}'.format(src, dst))
        more_paths = getAllSimplePaths(dst, [src], {src}, nodeToNodes, [])
        print('    {}'.format(pformat(more_paths)))
        all_paths.extend(more_paths)

    print('\nall paths: {}'.format(pformat(all_paths)))

def getAllSimplePaths(targetNode, currentPath, usedNodes, nodeToNodes, answerPaths):
    lastNode = currentPath[-1]
    if lastNode == targetNode:
        answerPaths.append(currentPath[:])
    elif lastNode in nodeToNodes:
        for neighbor in nodeToNodes[lastNode]:
            if neighbor not in usedNodes:
                currentPath.append(neighbor)
                usedNodes.add(neighbor)
                getAllSimplePaths(targetNode, currentPath, usedNodes, nodeToNodes,
                                  answerPaths)
                usedNodes.remove(neighbor)
                currentPath.pop()

    return answerPaths

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Output:

```
a:
 [['1', '2'], ['1', '0'], ['0', '2']]

nodeToNodes:
 {'0': ['2'], '1': ['2', '0']}

gathering results:
  1 <-> 2
    [['1', '2'], ['1', '0', '2']]
  1 <-> 0
    [['1', '0']]
  0 <-> 2
    [['0', '2']]

all paths: [['1', '2'], ['1', '0', '2'], ['1', '0'], ['0', '2']]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well for small csv files. I tried applying it for my csv file that has 2000 rows and it runs infinitely. Is there a way of doing this more efficiently?

Comment: You're welcome. I noticed that due to the printing I had inside the last `for` loop in `main()`, the `getAllSimplePaths()` function was being called _twice_ for the same pair of nodes. I've removed this from my answer which will make it faster. Don't know how much for your 2000 row csv file, though...

Comment: I've made a few more optimizations to speed it up. If you want to provide the 2000 row csv file (via a download link), I'll see if there's anything more I can do—assuming it's still too slow.